# taking string and integer in structure variable

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct book
{
  char name[1000];
  int price;
};

int main()

{

    struct book ct1[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
    printf("Please Enter %d Number Book Name: ",i+1);
    gets(ct1[i].name);
    printf("Price: ");
    scanf("%d", &ct1[i].price);
  }

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d Nuumber Book's name and price : \n",i+1);
    printf("%s = %d\n", ct1[i].name, ct1[i].price);
}


return 0;

}
```

I write this code to take book names and price and to print it.

like

input:
Please Enter 1 Number Book Name: Sherlock

price:100

...................

...................

output:

Number Book's name and price:
Sherlock = 100

.................

................

but it taking input like this
Please Enter 1 Number Book Name: sherlock holmes

price: 100

Please Enter 2 Number Book Name: price: ........

first time it is correct but from the second time something goes wrong. please help me.

Comment: What exactly "goes wrong"? And don't use `gets` but `fgets` instead!

Comment: `scanf("%d"` --> `scanf("%d%*c"`

Comment: it stop taking string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all stop using `gets`, use `fgets` instead -

```
fgets(ct1[i].name,sizeof ct1[i].name,stdin );
```

And after your `scanf` you can do this -

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n');
```

declare `c` as `int` before `for` loop .

This is to remove `'\n'` from `stdin` which remains after `scanf` in each iteration and causes `fgets` to return .

Comment: it works perfectly. can you please explain how is this while loop working?

Comment: @TawhidurRahmanTanim Value returned from `getchar` is assigned to `c`  . If value returned and stored in `c` is `EOF` or `'\n'` loop exits  and if not then loop extracted ,until `EOF` or `'\n'` is encountered . In this way if `'\n'` is present in `stdin` it is read from it .

Answer (score 0):

After `scanf` include this line to remove the newline character remaining in stdin

```
fflush(stdin)
```

Comment: Never knew that. Thanks a lot @chux